# when trying to install package, upgrade or update, I get the same probleme: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: java, dpkg

```
vmiaffossa@phd-vmiaffossa:~$ sudo apt-get install  openjdk-8-jre-headless
sudo: unable to resolve host phd-vmiaffossa
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java java-common
Suggested packages:
  default-jre equivs openjdk-8-jre-jamvm fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-ipafont-gothic
  fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-wqy-microhei ttf-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java java-common openjdk-8-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 113 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/63,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 276 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up udev (219-7ubuntu6) ...
Job for systemd-udevd.service failed. See "systemctl status systemd-udevd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
 systemd depends on udev; however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
          E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

please, can someone suggest something to solve it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 1):

It seems ***udev*** is not installed all the way or has an error in the package.


Using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` should attempt to fix the problem.


If that should not work, find the udev package in  `/var/cache/apt/archives/udev...` and use that .deb in 
`dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/udev...` that will for the install of udev and should solve the problem you are having.


excerpt of the Questions log file

> `Setting up udev (219-7ubuntu6) ...
>   Job for systemd-udevd.service failed. See "systemctl status systemd-udevd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>   invoke-rc.d: initscript udev, action "restart" failed.
>   dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of systemd:
>    systemd depends on udev; however:
>     Package udev is not configured yet.`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Fabby I edited the answer with more detail

Comment: Fantastic!  Upvoted!